# Unable to update Laravel 4 with Composer (Update: bug?)

Tags: php, cmd, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

Today, I pulled down the `laravel/laravel` repository from Github. I then ran `php composer.phar install` (as I normally would on my system, with a command window in the project directory). However, when I ran `php composer.phar update`, I received this error:

[image: composer.phar could not find file: artisan]

Everything installed just fine, and Laravel works as it should.

Any ideas what could be causing this issue?

## Edit 1

`artisan` exists in the root of the project, but it throws an exception when I attempt to run `php artisan optimize`:

[image: PHP Exception]

## Side Note 1

If I try the alternative method (quicker) of installing Laravel (`php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel`), I get the following:

[image: Create Project Fail]

## Edit 2

Upon installation, I also get the same error, where it claims it cannot find `artisan`. Therefore, the installation does not fully complete. I believe that it is stopping when it wants to compile classes (or something to that effect), and then write `bootstrap/compiled.php`. That file doesn't exist.

Here's the snap from the install:

[image: Install Fail]

## Edit 3

It seems that Composer is looking for `artisan` in the drive root (`C:\`). Why is it doing this? Even if I specify `-d` on the update, it throws the error. (I picked this up from a hunch - simply copied `artisan` to the root of the drive and it found it - albeit, it obviously did not run...)

Comment: (I think I'll stop adding edits now - I think everyone get's the point... Any help will be fantastic - thanks.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution Found:

Composer makes calls to `php artisan <command>` (as per the instruction in `composer.json > scripts`), but it does not see what directory it is running from (perhaps because it is an external command?).

So, I solved my initial problem by using an absolute path to `artisan` in `composer.json`.

Everything is working now. I just wish I knew how to get Composer to know that it is running from `C:\LocalServer\lab\laravel`, and not just `C:\`.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see, your artisan file is missing. Can you post the exact steps on how you install it ?
Also, please follow http://laravel.com/docs/installation and http://niallobrien.me/2013/03/installing-and-updating-laravel-4/

Comment: The `artisan` file is there. I can safely run `php artisan optimize`. No problems there. (Okay, wait. There seems to a problem with it. It can't find something - will post an update.)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today too. My laravel folder inside the vendor was deleted after composer update. I ran composer install again and problem resolved.

Comment: As per my solution above (or wherever StackOverflow feels like placing it), check your drive root - there might be a `laravel` folder in there. I wouldn't be surprised if there was one.